# How to detect if a media file is DRM protected in ANDROID?

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, android-videoview, mpeg-4

I trying to play a MPEG4 file using Android VideoView(Media Player). But it gives out the following error. Here is the logs.

```
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): setDataSource(), player type = 4
DEBUG/MediaPlayerService(64): setDataSource(), player type = **STAGEFRIGHT_PLAYER**
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): [17] setVideoSurface(0x35718)
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): [17] setVideoSurface(0x16fd8)
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): [17] setAudioStreamType(3)
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): [17] prepareAsync
VERBOSE/MediaExtractor(64): **FAILED to autodetect media content.**
VERBOSE/MediaPlayerService(64): [17] notify (0x403a0, 100, 1, -2147483648)
ERROR/MediaPlayer(7546): error (1, -2147483648)
INFO/MediaPlayer(7546): MediaPlayer handleMessage what=100
ERROR/MediaPlayer(7546): **Error (1,-2147483648)**
DEBUG/VideoView(7546): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

From the forums I figured out that if the MPEG4 video is DRM protected it cant be played in Android.

- How find whether a media is DRM protected?
- Is there is way I can remove the DRM protection before playing the media with videoview?
- The best way to stream video in android? The same MPEG4 video streams prefectly in iPhone but in android it doesnt? can anyone explain this please.

Thanks in advance.